# Block textbox for input in userform

Tags: excel, block, userform, vba

I am using a userform for the first time and I want a textbox to be blocked for input. I have tried a lot of different things, but still without a proper result.
Can anybody help me with this matter ?

Comment: Why are you using a textbox (designed for user input) if you don't want to allow input? Use a label instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Enabled property to False for the textbox.

Comment: I did that, and now when I try to type something, it jumps direct to the next textbox, and the character I typed in the textbox is grey.

Comment: Private Sub Achternaam_Change()
Me.Achternaam.Enabled = False
End Sub

Comment: @Chielmos: *I did that, and now when I try to type something* makes no sense when you've said *I want a textbox to be blocked for input*. Make up your mind. You **either** want it blocked for input or you want it to be able to be typed in (which is the **exact opposite** of *blocked for input*). What **exactly** are you asking here?

Comment: Robby, rather than answering very low quality, unclear questions it's better to just wait until the poster has made it more clear. It wastes less of your time, and provides incentive for the poster to make the edit.

Comment: @Ken White: I will try to make it more clear what I want to achieve. I have made a userForm with 20 different textboxes. I want to show the information in these textboxes, but it should not be possible for a user to change the values in some of these textboxes. In that case the displayed information has to be grey. I hope I explained my question a little bit better now.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want the user to be able to change or select the text in the textbox, Change the enabled Property to False.  This will grey out the textbox and make the text un-editable.

If you don't want it greyed out, try setting the focus on another control as soon as a user enters your textbox

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
    TextBox2.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you funnyjugler, this for me the right solution